# MySQL Union query duplicate/group by problem

Tags: mysql, union

Just learning about UNION queries - what a timesaver - but having trouble with grouping.

I have the following statement:

```
(SELECT `shops`.shpUserAdded AS userName, count(`shops`.shpID) AS shpCount, "" AS prdCount FROM `shops` GROUP BY shpUserAdded ASC)
UNION
(SELECT `products`.prdUserAdded AS userName, "" AS shpCount, count(`products`.prdID) AS prdCount FROM `products` GROUP BY prdUserAdded ASC)
```

but this gives me the results from the first query followed by the results of the second query, without combining the usernames:

```
userName|merCount|prdCount 
        |       8|
Jane    |       1|
Derek   |       1|
James   |      22|
        |        |       3
Jane    |        |       4  
Derek   |        |       5
James   |        |      21
```

I tried (but obviously got `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`):

```
SELECT userName, shpCount, prdCount FROM
((SELECT `shops`.shpUserAdded AS userName, count(`shops`.shpID) AS shpCount, "" AS prdCount FROM `shops` GROUP BY shpUserAdded ASC)
UNION
(SELECT `products`.prdUserAdded AS userName, "" AS shpCount, count(`products`.prdID) AS prdCount FROM `products` GROUP BY prdUserAdded ASC))
GROUP BY userName ASC
```

I can't seem to figure out naming the derived table(s) without wiping out the data from either the shpCount or prdCount column - any suggestions?  I'm probably going to feel stupid but thereyago!

Solved it (really this time)! :)

```
SELECT Users.userName, Products.prdCount, Shops.shpCount FROM 
(
    (
        (SELECT `Shops`.shpAddU AS userName FROM `Shops` GROUP BY shpAddU ASC)
        UNION
        (SELECT `Products`.prdAddU AS userName FROM `Products` GROUP BY prdAddU ASC)
    ) AS Users
) 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT prdAddU AS userName, count(*) AS prdCount FROM `Products` GROUP BY prdAddU) as Products ON Users.userName = Products.userName
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT shpAddU AS userName, count(*) AS shpCount FROM `Shops` GROUP BY shpAddU) as Shops ON Users.userName = Shops.userName
```

Answer (score 4):

Not everything is a union -- in this case it's a join on the subqueries:

```
SELECT shpUserAdded AS userName, merCount, prdCount
FROM (SELECT shpUserAdded, count(*) AS shpCount FROM shops GROUP BY shpUserAdded ASC) AS s
JOIN (SELECT prdUserAdded, count(*) AS prdCount FROM products GROUP BY prdUserAdded ASC) AS p
ON (shpUserAdded = prdUserAdded);
```

Comment: Thanks!  Except ... a user might not be in both tables - users are stored in .htpasswd not in the database so I can't query the table (or at least I don't know how to extract those values), so I really need a single list of the usernames that appear in both tables and can't rely on the list in 's' or elsewhere.

Comment: You can do `OUTER JOIN`s if you want to include unmatched rows.

Comment: If I don't put OUTER in that statement, I get the prdCount and shpCount on one line, but without users only in the products table, as expected.  I'm not familiar with outer joins - if I just put 'OUTER' before 'JOIN' I get a syntax error.

Comment: ... if (after a quick bit of research) I have to specify LEFT or RIGHT, I can't, because there could be unmatched entries on both sides.